# Qt/C++ include classes without calling them directly in the core code

Tags: c++, qt, class, module

My need is to easily write new classes with predefined methods(predefined method names) and use the in my main program without touching the main program.

Consider a file structure like bellow:

```
C:\myprogram\main.cpp
C:\myprogram\main.cpp
C:\myprogram\modules\printMethod1.cpp
C:\myprogram\modules\printMethod1.h
C:\myprogram\modules\contributorPrintMethod.cpp
C:\myprogram\modules\contributorPrintMethod.h
```

Under modules would be all the possible classes can be used from the program(they would have to follow a template -- like method names in order to get used by the main program). Main program would not need to be recompiled but only link to the classes. The main program should not have direct "includes" to the modules. The idea is that you can add classes without need to touch the main code.

Is this possible? Using some macro in the modules classes would be able to register them in my main program somehow?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you want some sort of plugin mechanism, you should look into the [Qt plugin framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html).

Comment: I thought If there is a more Qt independent way of doing it. Like in a pure C++ enviroment.

Comment: Just good old C++ virtual methods?

Comment: But how I iterate then to all new classes added? And how I tell the compiler to include these files?(without touching the main program and .pro file)